# How to show actual values on MongoDB Compass Schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-schema

As the question suggests when analzing via Schema how does one view the actual number of records for a category rather than a percentage?

For example I have daily records of totalRiders per hour with a season attribute, I have filtered for a Winter Season however the totalRiders are showing as bins with a percentage value where I would like the actual value. [Img Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gACes.png).

Comment: also, I have filtered for required specifications. One of the columns is a Total column with an integer value. I want to find the total of adding all these integer values, is this possible via the Aggregations or Schema methods? Cheers.

Comment: Aggregations can be used to get such stats too. Also group stage would help if you want to get counts or sum/total. Sample aggregation for your reference https://mongoplayground.net/p/dZvbejg8Tox